# change new line into space for selected lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file which have input like :

```
Application handle                         = 36768
  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36433
Application handle                         = 36807
  ID of agent holding lock                 = 53074
Application handle                         = 52994
Application handle                         = 36433
Application handle                         = 36581
  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36580
Application handle                         = 36458
```

but i want output in below format:

```
Application handle                         = 36768  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36433
Application handle                         = 36807  ID of agent holding lock                 = 53074
Application handle                         = 52994
Application handle                         = 36433
Application handle                         = 36581  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36580
Application handle                         = 36458
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i have tried, tr and awk getline nextline but they did not work out.. :(

Comment: Please be *specific* about what you have tried that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This awk works:

```
awk '$1 == "Application"{if (l) print l; l=$0; next}
     {l=l $0; next} END {print l}' file

Application handle                         = 36768  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36433
Application handle                         = 36807  ID of agent holding lock                 = 53074
Application handle                         = 52994
Application handle                         = 36433
Application handle                         = 36581  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36580
Application handle                         = 36458
```

#### Explanation:

This awk first evaluates this condition:

- `$1 == "Application"` to check whether a line start with `"Application"`.
  If condition matches then it does this first

  - `if (l) print l;` to print value of l **if l is not null**
  - Then it sets `l=$0` to set value of `variable l` as `$0` (full line)
  - finally it calls `next` to make awk move to next record
- Then second `{...}` is evaluated only when `$1 != "Application"` (line to be joined)
- That block is `{l=l $0; next}` which appends 2nd line to the `variable l` calls `next`
- This cycle goes on till last line and finally
- `END {print l}` is called to print the last line.

Comment: Yes sure, let me add my explanation to answer.

Comment: @user2194036: Explanation added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> no, i want to remove the next line only when next line is "ID of agent
>   holding lock"

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n\(.*ID of agent holding lock\)/\1/;ta' -e 'P;D' filename
```

For your input, it'd return:

```
Application handle                         = 36768  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36433
Application handle                         = 36807  ID of agent holding lock                 = 53074
Application handle                         = 52994
Application handle                         = 36433
Application handle                         = 36581  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36580
Application handle                         = 36458
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a perl based version

```
$ perl -lpe'$\=q{:}' data | perl -lne's,:$,,; s,:\s, ,g; s,:,\n,g; print'
Application handle                         = 36768  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36433
Application handle                         = 36807  ID of agent holding lock                 = 53074
Application handle                         = 52994
Application handle                         = 36433
Application handle                         = 36581  ID of agent holding lock                 = 36580
Application handle                         = 36458
```

the second perl on the pipe can be substituted by a sed equivalent